# dpkg-buildpackage build is failing to find pip dependencies

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-12.04, dpkg

I've got a build that's failing, and I've spent the better part of two days tracking down and fixing multiple problems with the build machine.  Now it's getting stuck on a part that makes no sense, because what it's doing doesn't seem to follow from the input.

It's running dpkg-buildpackage, and erroring out on the `fakeroot debian/build binary` step.  Here's the part of the build log where it fails:

```
Collecting lazy-object-proxy (from astroid==1.5.2->-r ./requirements.txt (line 2))
  0 location(s) to search for versions of lazy-object-proxy:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lazy-object-proxy (from astroid==1.5.2->-r ./requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/user/1000/pip-build-5s7d8it1/gevent
  Removing source in /tmp/user/1000/pip-build-5s7d8it1/greenlet
  Removing source in /tmp/user/1000/pip-build-5s7d8it1/Pillow
  Removing source in /tmp/user/1000/pip-build-5s7d8it1/PyYAML
  Removing source in /tmp/user/1000/pip-build-5s7d8it1/wrapt
No matching distribution found for lazy-object-proxy (from astroid==1.5.2->-r ./requirements.txt (line 2))
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/project-a/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 704, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 439, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 244, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 563, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for lazy-object-proxy (from astroid==1.5.2->-r ./requirements.txt (line 2))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dh_virtualenv", line 106, in <module>
    sys.exit(main() or 0)
  File "/usr/bin/dh_virtualenv", line 86, in main
    deploy.install_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dh_virtualenv/deployment.py", line 165, in install_dependencies
    subprocess.check_call(self.pip('-r', requirements_path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/bin/python', '/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/bin/pip', '-v', 'install', '--log=/tmp/user/1000/tmpYI75My', '--no-index', '--find-links=pypi', '-r', './requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_virtualenv] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/project-name'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build-dpkg", line 116, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(args=sys.argv[1:]))
  File "./build-dpkg", line 34, in main
    build_package()
  File "./build-dpkg", line 104, in build_package
    check_call('dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc'.split())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dpkg-buildpackage', '-us', '-uc']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Here's the rules file it's trying to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv

override_dh_virtualenv:
    DH_VIRTUALENV_INSTALL_ROOT=/opt/company-name dh_virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.5 --extra-pip-arg --no-index \
    --extra-pip-arg --find-links=pypi -v --no-test
```

We have a `pypi` folder that houses local copies of dependencies.  Both `astroid` and `lazy-object-proxy` are present in this folder.

Looking at the output, it appears that the command it's trying to run that's failing is:

> /home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/bin/python /home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/bin/pip -v install --no-index --find-links=pypi -r ./requirements.txt

If I run that same command on the command line, I can reproduce the failure.  But if I change the first part (the executable name with the long path) to simply "python", everything runs as expected.  But I can't see why it's using that long path in the first place, when the environment specifies `--python=/usr/bin/python3.5`!

Does anyone have any idea where this rogue Python invocation is coming from, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to use an absolute path for `--find-links` ?

Comment: *Does anyone have any idea where this rogue Python invocation is coming from?* It is a Python virtual environment created by the `dh_virtualenv` command in your recipe for the `override_dh_virtualenv` target. `/home/username/project-name/debian/project-name/opt/company-name/project-name/bin/python` should be a identical copy of `/usr/bin/python3.5`. Still, functionally they are not identical, since the latter has access to system packages, while the former is restricted to the virtual environment.